# initialize const variable with extra check

Tags: c++, initialization, constants, initializer-list

I've the following `struct`:

```
// options for pool_base-based pools
struct pool_options
{
    // pool initial_size
    const uint32 initial_size;

    // can pool grow?
    const bool can_grow;
    // if minimum free space by percent?
    // true for percentage size, false for fixed-amount-of-bytes minimum.
    const bool min_by_percent;
    // minimum value.
    const uint32 minimum_size;
    // is growth by percentage?
    // true for percentage size, false for fixed-amount-of-bytes growth.
    const bool grow_by_percent;
    // growth value.
    const uint32 grow_size;

    // true to prevent manager from free up extra space.
    const bool keep_extra_space;
    // is shrinkage by percent?
    // true for percentage size, false for fixed-amount-of-bytes shrinkage.
    const bool max_by_percent;
    // maximum value.
    const uint32 maximum_size;

    // is defragment occur by percent?
    // true for percentage defragment, false for fixed-amount-of-bytes defragment.
    //
    // if percentage of fragmented memory from total memory occur then defragment take place.
    const bool defrag_by_percent;
    // fragment size
    const uint32 fragment_size;
};
```

I'll initialize the constants inside the constructor initializer list, but the problem is i need to do extra check to validate the input values but that causes the compiler to signal the `l-value specifies const object` error. The code for the constructor:

```
pool_options(uint32 is, bool cg, bool mip, uint32 mis, bool gp, uint32 gs, bool kes, bool map, uint32 mas, bool dp, uint32 fs)
    : initial_size(is), can_grow(cg), min_by_percent(mip), minimum_size(mis), grow_by_percent(gp),
      grow_size(gs), keep_extra_space(kes), max_by_percent(map), maximum_size(mas), defrag_by_percent(dp), fragment_size(fs)
{
    if (can_grow)
    {
        if (min_by_percent && minimum_size > 100) minimum_size = 100;
        if (grow_by_percent && grow_size > 100) grow_size = 100;
    }
    else
    {
        min_by_percent = false;
        minimum_size = 0;
        grow_by_percent = false;
        grow_size = 0;
    }

    if (keep_extra_space)
    {
        max_by_percent = false;
        maximum_size = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (max_by_percent && maximum_size > 100) maximum_size = 100;
    }

    if (defrag_by_percent)
    {
        if (fragment_size > 100) fragment_size = 100;
    }

}
```

The `struct` is for a memory manager i currently working on and the variable must be constants so once it assigned it can never changes by other classes.

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: You need to do the validation in the member initializer list. You do need to be careful with the order of initialization of members. You might even call functions within the initializer list to perform these checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a checker member function, for example:

```
struct Test
{
    const int x;

    Test(int x) : x(checkX(x)) // <--------- check the value
    {
       std::cout << this->x << std::endl;
    }

private:

    int checkX(int x) const
    {
        if (x < 0 || x > 100)
            return 0;
        else
            return x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t(-10);
}
```

Comment: If i cast `minimum_size` to `uint32&` - using old-style cast - then assigned the value to it, would that compile under `clang` or `gcc`?

Comment: @Muhammadalaa: You can not cast an `uint32` to a `uint32&`.

Comment: like this `uint32& minimum_size_ref = (uint32&)minimum_size;`, ain't that a valid code?

Comment: Try this `const uint32& minimum_size_ref = minimum_size;`